# Identifying unused Step Types in ArcGIS Workflow Manager (WMX)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-workflow-manager, administration

Is there a way to bulk identify unused step types using ArcGIS Workflow Manager Administrator?

Perhaps someone has worked up (*and is willing to share*) a SQL select statement that returns unused step types.